# How to add hotspots dynamically using lat, long values from db/json source in Krpano

Tags: javascript, 360-degrees, 360-panorama, krpano, virtual-tour

I want to add hotspot dynamically in each panorama. I have latitude, longitude and heading of each panorama, I just want to add some markers eg. coffee house with an icon.
With Krpano editor I can add a few hotspots but for larger number of panorama it becomes impossible to add hotspot manually.
What I have understood so far is,
krpano place hotspot based on `atv` and `ath` values.
I need some formula that converts latitude, longitude of a POI to `atv`, `ath` values for a hotspot.

Comment: Is this question still actual?